# Extracting text from PDF is null in some cases using iText

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am having an issue where extracting text from some PDF files are showing up null. The code works normally, but I came across a file, that it could not read text from.  The PDF that causes an issue is using a TT3 font. I thought maybe this was the problem, but I cannot find any issue or information on this specific question or problem. The following code is what I am doing currently to extract the text from all other PDFs and it works, just not from the PDF's using TT# fonts.

```
iTextExtractionStrategy = pdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());

PdfText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReaderInput, i)

pdfText = iTextExtractionStrategy.GetResultantText();
```

Any information on this would be extremely helpful, or if anyone else has had the same issue so that I can isolate to see if it is the Library or, the PDF's using TT3 are corrupt. I have even opened the documents that do not work, and saved them in a PDF reader to see if it was corrupt, and it changed nothing.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please supply the PDF in question.

Comment: I would of, but cannot do so. It is a statement file.

Comment: Basically, just create a statement that uses custom font. It makes sense on why it can't recognize it, but seems like it would use the font that is embedded for mapping purposes or somthing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that you cannot read TT fonts unless having do some OCR type work. What I did was start looking into the meta data and comments to get what I needed. Will not work for every scenario obviously, but did in this case.